# JAXB Schema Validation with generic XML Types

Tags: xml, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a requirement where the XML payload gets delivered inside an envelope where the payload is defined as an org.w3c.dom.Element.

Each payload needs to be validated against it's schema (there are about 40) and many of them have imports to other schemas.

The code attached currently validates but I'm convinced that its only validating it again the generated schema (XMLDocument) and as it's well formed, it passes validation.

I've seen examples of how to validate against specific schemas - but I won't know until parse time what subclass of Document the payload will be.

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions......

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance();
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

        QName qName = new QName("");
        JAXBElement<Object> rootElement = new JAXBElement<Object>(qName, Object.class, message.getPayload());

        JAXBSource theXML = new JAXBSource(jaxbContext, rootElement);

        SchemaFactory schemaFactory = Schema.Factory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema();

        jaxbUnmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
        Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
        validator.setErrorHandler(new CustomValidationErrorHandler());

        validator.validate(theXML);
```

Comment: Add a sample of your payload please. Anyway, [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/xml/bind/jaxb-schema-validation-example/) is an example of validation against a specific schema `Schema schema = sf.newSchema(new File("Employee.xsd"));`. In your code, you are validating against a generic one it seems.

Comment: Thanks - but how do I determine the schema to use as it could be one of 40 possible ones? Is it a case of having to manually parse the first part of the document to find the schema definition? I can't add an example for security reasons.....

Answer (score 0):

Based on some feedback from elsewhere I went down the parse it via SAX or DOM route, and let the parser determine if it's valid or not by using the self discovery mechanism of the parser for finding the XSD for the document.